# ajax and php won't work together

Tags: php, ajax

Here is the whole html code:

```
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function send()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
         else
           {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
             }
           }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","add.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send('subject=' + document.getElementById("subject").value);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="main" method="post" action="add.php">
<div align="center">    
<table border="1" frame="hsides" rules="rows" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="50%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            subject: 
        </td>
        <td width="80%" align="right">
            <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="subject" id="subject" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="50%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="80%">
            <input type="button" value="send" onclick="send();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the add.php code:

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
echo $subject;
?>
```

I get error: notice undefined index on line 2, in the add.php.
In the alert thats what I get..
Can anyone tell me whats the problem? I'm getting insane with this error.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this line between the `xmlhttp.open()` and `xmlhttp.send()` calls:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

PHP will not know how to decode the content you are sending unless you tell it what type of content it is.

Comment: The MIME type of a request string like that (`key=val&key2=val2`) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you don't tell PHP what type of content you are sending, it won't know what to do with it. It is important that you send the correct headers with requests and responses when you build them yourself - browsers work it out for themselves, but a programmable HTTP client like XMLHTTPRequest is not always capable of doing so.